# Is clang working on linux

Tags: linux, clang

I know that clang isn't fully working on windows yet, but I was just wondering if the situation is different for linux platform. Can someone give some insight into this topic?

Comment: Not quite a real question, [of course it is](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html)...

Comment: @EdwardA well, I didn't mean if I can download it, but rather if after compiling them from the source code will I be able to write code other than simple examples, as it is on windows at the moment, would you know anything about it?

Comment: I linked you the download page because it has links to binaries for ubuntu, freeBSD etc, the experimental ones for mingw are clearly marked as so. Theres also a c++11 [status page here](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html). It seems like most of the important stuff works. For a comparison, theres also apache's [c++11 compiler support](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport) page that includes information about clang, gcc etc.

Comment: Big part of the [Debian](http://clang.debian.net/) archive can be compiled with clang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Clang works on Linux. If you are on a Debian or Ubuntu system try something like:

```
sudo apt get install clang
```

The above will install the available Clang for your system. If you feel adventurous and you want to have the latest Clang and libc++ on your Linux you can build it from sources. This a good step by step tutorial:

http://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/01/17/building-clang-libcpp-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: hey, thanks, will try it as soon as I manage to make my mobile broadband working on linux mint

Comment: thanks, just finished building clang33. Great!