# Installing clang on linux mint

Tags: linux, clang

I'm trying to install clang according to:
[Is clang working on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519158/is-clang-working-on-linux)
but I'm getting the following error:

E: Unable to locate package clang

Any ideas how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clang was removed at some point. "Might need to change your sources.list to point to Debian testing."

Taken from here http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&t=102090&p=579467

Comment: Would you know how am I supposed to change my sources.list?

Comment: hi, finally I've sorted it out. a) don't use clang which comes with Mint 14 - is outdated, get the source from official web and build it with gcc. Simple. Thanks.